# Error when moving partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, efi

I'm trying to move the partition hfs to the right of the unnalocated space in this image:

[image: my screenshot]

I'm getting the following error:

[image: my 2. screenshot]

```
GParted 0.19.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Move /dev/sda3 to the right and shrink it from 617.00 MiB to 616.00 MiB  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda3  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda3
start: 117597144
end: 118860759
size: 1263616 (617.00 MiB)
check file system on /dev/sda3 for errors and (if possible) fix them    ( N/A )

checking is not available for this file system
shrink file system  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

using libparted
shrink partition from 617.00 MiB to 616.00 MiB  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

old start: 117597144
old end: 118860759
old size: 1263616 (617.00 MiB)
new start: 117597144
new end: 118858711
new size: 1261568 (616.00 MiB)
check file system on /dev/sda3 for errors and (if possible) fix them    ( N/A )

checking is not available for this file system
grow partition from 616.00 MiB to 56.93 GiB  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

old start: 117597144
old end: 118858711
old size: 1261568 (616.00 MiB)
requested start: 117597144
requested end: 236978175
requested size: 119381032 (56.93 GiB)
libparted messages    ( INFO )

Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.

========================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem to be errors, but more that check is not possible.Be sure you have HFS+ tools : hfsprogs (for mkfs and fsck) and hfsutils.